# Actor-based distributed concurrency libraries for Ocaml and other languages

Tags: scala, erlang, ocaml, distributed, actor

### Question

Can anyone recommend a library for Ocaml that offers an *actor-based concurrency model* for *distributed computing*?

Note here the "actor-based" and "distributed" - I'd like the actor-based model, but also I want seamless handling of distributed actors - I don't want to write the protocol to talk to them. The library should ideally also offer standard patterns such a supervisor trees and so on.

---

### Motivation

I love Erlang concurrency model and ability to transparently deal with distributed processes and local processes together. However, I find Erlang's syntax to be rather limiting and would like a much more expressive language. I'm considering moving from Erlang to either Scala or Ocaml.

I know Scala has the Akka library which seems to offer a nice Scala version of Erlang's concurrency model. I'd like to see what is available on the Ocaml side.

---

### Aside

I'd also be happy to hear about actor-based concurrency libraries for other languages (particularly C++, Haskell, Python and Ruby).

Comment: in a language whose implementation still doesn't support multithreading, what would one do with an actor library?

Comment: there is more than one implementation

Comment: @KimStebel: Multithreading is no prerequisite for distributed computing.  In fact, you can use Erlang without any SMP as well.

Comment: erlang has language level support for actors, that is hardly comparable.

Comment: @ygrek: is there one that supports multithreading?

Comment: Note that Scala _comes_ with an Actor library based on Erlang. Akka is an alternative library which departs a bit from Erlang model for various reasons. There are two other Actor libraries for Scala as well.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral , but does the standard Actor library offer reasonable support for distributed computing? The reason I mention Akka is that it seems to be geared to this.

Comment: Kim Stebel, to be precise, inria's ocaml supports multithreading. But you probably meant SMP - and there is oc4mc. Linear performance suffers, as expected.

Comment: @MGwynne Akka _is_ geared for it, and it is superior to the standard library implementation. Who said replicating Erlang model in all its details is best? In particular, Erlang has a VM made specifically for what it does, why Scala has to run on JVM, subject to different strengths and limitations.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here: actors are running in completely different processes, right (CSP)?  Why is the threading issue relevant?  OK, I can see that each actor needs a thread to pull messages off the incoming queue and another to send messages out - but OCaml's threads seem to be sufficient for that, right?

Comment: @ygrek - are you saying there is more than one implementation of actors in OCaml?

Comment: aneccodeal, no, I was talking about ocaml implementations/forks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it may not be the exact same model that Erlang uses, you might want to take a look at [JoCaml](http://jocaml.inria.fr/), which is based on the join calculus.

Comment: Looks interesting! Any idea how popular/well-used/supported this is? I'd rather not use something actively-developed that is going to lose support within a year.

Comment: I'm not sure about adoption.  A data point: the mailing list archives are pretty much empty.  In addition, at some point, development ceased for a while (2003-2007, I believe).  On the other hand, JoCaml has been in existence for quite a number of years.  I wouldn't expect a lot of API instability.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at [parvel](https://bitbucket.org/gds/parvel) -- message passing library/framework for ocaml. It's not yet complete, but already includes some primitives for programming with actors.

Answer (score 3):

"I'm considering moving from Erlang to either Scala or Ocaml."

You should consider scalang, which allows you to program in Scala, but use Erlang's actors.

I recently saw a talk on the language by @moonpolysoft (Cliff Moon) at the Strange Loop conference. Cliff Moon developed it for https://boundary.com/ and open-sourced it earlier this year.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably spend a lot of time reading about:

Scala and F# have akka and [MailboxProcessor](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/MailboxProcessor) which are being used in production apps (note: Scala actors and, I think, akka, are very tied to Hotspot; I'm not sure if MailboxProcessor can be used under MONO)

Haskell has userspace threads and [at least 1 actor implementation](http://coder.bsimmons.name/blog/2011/05/simple-actors-a-simple-actor-model-concurrency-library/) which i don't know a lot about

For ML and ocaml, some libs which are probably not widely used: [poly/ML](http://functional-orbitz.blogspot.com/2011/04/jc-efficient-parallel-programming-in.html) and [oc4mc](http://www-apr.lip6.fr/~pwang/)

and [netmulticore](http://blog.camlcity.org/blog/multicore2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Although, it is a very old question things have changed since it was asked. C++ has an actor model implementation which is quite robust. It also provides distributed computing features as asked by OP. The homepage is at http://actor-framework.org/

Further, it can also make us of OpenCL for HPC the module for which is located at github in one of the repositories.